# Count in mysql with more than one table

Tags: mysql, count

I have tow tables (MySQL) :

forum : match_static_id,comments,...

matches : static_id, .........

the sql statement:

```
SELECT  forum.match_static_id, count(forum.comments) 'comments_no', matches.* 
from forum 
INNER JOIN matches ON forum.match_static_id = matches.static_id   
group by forum.match_static_id
```

I do not get the right number of comments for each match (it always multiply the number of the comments example 4 comments it returns 8)even I use group by. Is my sql wrong I just want a clue from you please ?

Comment: As it stands, your query looks OK. Will you ever have more than one record on matches for a given static_id?

Comment: no static_id is unique

Comment: Can you add some sample data (that should replicate the issue) to the question?

Answer (score -1):

You should use Left join insted of inner

`SELECT  forum.match_static_id, count(forum.comments) 'comments_no', matches.* 
from matches
LEFT JOIN forum ON forum.match_static_id = matches.static_id

group by forum.match_static_id`

Comment: Won't resolve his current problem, but would be a good idea in case there are matches with no comments.

Comment: No I query just matches with comments

Comment: i think that updated query should solve problem. There are match and comments for them in left join. You can put there IF NULL or sth. else to solve problem where there are no comments.

Comment: -1 for ignoring both the substance of the question and the comments on this answer.

Comment: Schema I have created:

`CREATE TABLE `forum` (
  `match_static_id` INT(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comments` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `FK_forum` (`match_static_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_forum` FOREIGN KEY (`match_static_id`) REFERENCES `matches` (`static_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `matches` (
  `static_id` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`static_id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;`

Comment: and populetes with data:
INSERT  INTO `matches`(`static_id`,`name`) VALUES (1,'11'),(2,'22'),(3,'33'),(4,'44');
INSERT  INTO `forum`(`match_static_id`,`comments`) VALUES (1,'111'),(2,'222'),(3,'333'),(3,'332'),(2,'223'),(3,'222'),(3,'222');

gave me good query result.